# Calling C++ functions from Python

Tags: c++, python-2.7

```
class ICallback
{
       public: virtual void OnEvent(int a,char*  b) = 0;
};
class MyListener :public ICallback
{
    public: virtual void OnEvent(int a, , char*  b){code here}
};

int OnComplete(char* ID, ICallback* Listener);
```

Hello, I have such code in C++ and I need to call OnComplete method from Python.

Please pay attention that I have to create MyListener in python, implement OnNavigationEvent in python and call OnComplete of C++.

Is it possible?

Update: I can't touch "OnComplete" method code, it's third party library

Update 2: Here is the perfect example, very compact and understandable for people like me, new for python: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/31/ctypes-calling-cc-code-from-python/ 
I just can't answer on my own question because a reputation < 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's not trivial; the process is too involved to try and describe it here.  Fortunately the Python team provides a [handy document that describes how to do it](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html#extending-index).

Comment: Jeremy's right... The Python docs are good, and often worth reading when you're trying to do something with Python